# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name unexpected call to public native int java.lang.Object.hashCode

Tags: spring, spring-orm

I'm upgrading Spring from 4.2.9 to 4.3.0
My rendering services are down after the upgrade. There is absolutely no code changes with respect to this upgrade.
But my services is not getting up.

Complete error logs:

```
2024-01-19 16:06:05,691  ERROR [com.services.rendering.RenderingServiceDaemon] [main] CRITICAL: unable to start rendering service. Exiting - 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'moduleDirector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: unexpected call to public native int java.lang.Object.hashCode()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at com.services.rendering.RenderingServiceDaemon.start(RenderingServiceDaemon.java:56)
    at com.services.rendering.RenderingServiceDaemon.main(RenderingServiceDaemon.java:80)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: unexpected call to public native int java.lang.Object.hashCode()
    at com.testutil.UnsupportedOperationFactoryBean$PlaceHolder.invoke(UnsupportedOperationFactoryBean.java:78)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy35.hashCode(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:936)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.containsKey(ConcurrentHashMap.java:964)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.requiresDestruction(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.hasApplicableProcessors(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:431)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.requiresDestruction(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.registerDisposableBeanIfNecessary(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1645)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:586)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at com.spring.module.ModuleInstance.loadConfig(ModuleInstance.java:65)
    at com.spring.module.ModuleInstance.load(ModuleInstance.java:50)
    at com.spring.module.ModuleDirector.init(ModuleDirector.java:115)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:365)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133)
    ... 13 more
```

I tried changing the xmlSchema versions in xml, it didnt work.